# Extract rows from dataframe inside list inside dataframe in R

Tags: r, package, pubmed

I'm using package RISmed in R in order to obtain information from PubMed. The 'Mesh' package function allows me to obtain the MeSH terms of each citation. Nevertheless it is a List, containing a Data Frame.
I want to list each MeSH term besides its corresponding citation id (PMID).
For example, I can construct a table containing both values:

```
table = cbind(ArticleId(MedlineObject),Mesh(MedlineObject))
```

The first column is a char object but the second one is a list, containing a dataframe. If the value inside 1st column were "29145282" and the content of 2dnd column were "Cardiomyopathy, Hypertrophic", "Combined Modality Therapy" and "Diagnosis, Differential", I would want to obtain:

```
"29145282","Cardiomyopathy, Hypertrophic"
"29145282","Combined Modality Therapy"
"29145282","Diagnosis, Differential"
```

How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Please try to provide [a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). At a minimum include the code which generated `MedlineObject`. Also, `table` is not a great variable name (there's a 
 function with the same name).

Comment: Hi neilfws, the example used by @TooYoung below it's a good one. "table" is not a good variable name, indeed. It wasn't the real one, only an example. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it works. Would you mind accepting that answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to use `myeloma` as an example of `medline object` since I don't have your data. `myeloma` is a medline data within `RISmed` package.

First add the id to all dataframes in your list by `mapply` and `cbind`:

```
MedList = mapply(cbind, "ID"=ArticleId(myeloma),Mesh(myeloma),SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

And then merge all list into one dataframe by `do.call` and `rbind`:

```
MedFrame = do.call("rbind",MedList)
```

You just need to change 'myeloma' in the code to your own MedlineObject

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `tidyr` and `tibble` packages. Make sure to take a look at the `nest()` and `unnest()` functions. I can't give you much more advice without a reproducible example.

```
x = 1:5
data <- lapply(x, function(i){
  data.frame(y = 1:5 * i)
})

temp = tibble::tibble(x, data)
temp
tidyr::unnest(temp)
```

Comment: i can't make comments